# Metabase/Clojure error: Unfreezable type: class org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray

Tags: postgresql, clojure, metabase

Anyone knows something about this error in Metabase (or a similar one in any Clojure program)?

```
Unfreezable type: class org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray
```

It happens regularly, but not always, when I use a postgresql array type (i.e. `TEXT[]`) in a question => it probably depends on the exact data in the pgArray somehow, but I wasn't able to figure out how.

There is a **workaround to get rid of it: retype/cast all pgArrays to TEXT (or VARCHAR)**. But I would really like to understand why this is happening. Thx for any insights.

Answer (score 2):

Metabase uses a library called Nippy:

https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/project.clj#L61

Nippy provides fast serialization of common types. The error "Unfreezable type":

https://github.com/ptaoussanis/nippy/blob/master/src/taoensso/nippy.clj#L720

occurs when Nippy comes across data of a type it doesn't know how to serialize. PgArray, as a bespoke Postgres array type, is evidently one of those.

Providing serialization guidance to Nippy is not hard. Maybe make an issue for the Metabase folks with your details asking if they can do this?

Comment: Thx for the info. The weird thing is though that sometimes the query runs even when pgArray types are there. So maybe it can only serialize some sort of pgArrays depending on the data in it and some it can't.

Comment: Yeah, maybe; I don't know metabase but my guess would be that serialization is a not-every-time operation. The app is for data visualization, right? In that case, it could make sense to serialize large result sets for local manipulation/visualization, and not bother doing that for small result sets. Or- serialize when the working set of data in use for the current workbook got above a certain size. Something like that. The serialization failure is on the PgArray type itself, so wherever that gets used, it won't be serializable.